# Pymongo find and modify

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a find query in a mongodb collection and would like this query to also update a field... something like this...

```
db = pymongo.MongoClient(DB_HOST)[COLLECTION][Product]
new_posts = db.find({'type':{'$ne':'overview'}, 'indice':0, 'thread_id':{'$nin':front_db_ids}, 'updated':{'$exists':False}},{'_id': 0}) + {{'$set': {'updated':'yes'}}, multi=True
```

I found the findandmodify method but could not find any example of how to use it...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that the methods in this answer have been deprecated. See [Sid Holland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165097/5083988) for more details.

---

refer the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update),
for example

```
db.update({"_id": acs_num}, {"$set": mydata}, upsert = True)
```

or `find_and_modify` according to [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) says `Returns either the object before or after modification based on new parameter. If no objects match the query and upsert is false, returns None. If upserting and new is false, returns {}`

for example:

```
In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [2]: client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
   ...: db = client["testdb"]
   ...: mycollection = db["mydb"]
   ...: 

In [3]: import datetime
   ...: post1 = {"author": "Mike", "text": "My first blog post!", "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"], "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
   ...: 

In [4]: mycollection.insert(post1)
Out[4]: ObjectId('535fd580c314f91d28c35ee1')

In [5]: [x for x in mycollection.find()]
Out[5]: 
[{u'_id': ObjectId('535fd580c314f91d28c35ee1'),
  u'author': u'Mike',
  u'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 29, 16, 38, 15, 457000),
  u'tags': [u'mongodb', u'python', u'pymongo'],
  u'text': u'My first blog post!'}]

In [6]: mycollection.find_and_modify(query={'author':'Mike'}, update={"$set": {'author': "Mike2"}}, upsert=False, full_response= True)
Out[6]: 
{u'lastErrorObject': {u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': True},
 u'ok': 1.0,
 u'value': {u'_id': ObjectId('535fd580c314f91d28c35ee1'),
  u'author': u'Mike',
  u'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 29, 16, 38, 15, 457000),
  u'tags': [u'mongodb', u'python', u'pymongo'],
  u'text': u'My first blog post!'}}

In [7]: [ x for x in mycollection.find()]
Out[7]: 
[{u'_id': ObjectId('535fd580c314f91d28c35ee1'),
  u'author': u'Mike2',
  u'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 29, 16, 38, 15, 457000),
  u'tags': [u'mongodb', u'python', u'pymongo'],
  u'text': u'My first blog post!'}]
```

Comment: This would only update, no? I was looking for a way to run a find query and then update the result of this query... I am actually doing it in 2 steps, first finding and then creating a list and after it updating the documents based on this list... was wondering if would be a way to do it in a single step...

Comment: above `update` query does the find and update in one step, first option find the document/documents, then rest options will update it.. .what else you want to do??

Comment: I see as a return from the above query just the confirmation of the operation... I would need it to return the documents it has changed as if in a find query...

Comment: then the easy step will be run the `find` query again in next line based on your `$set` or any other imp key that you have set during `update` query.. .

Comment: Yes, that is what I have found but could not find any working examples... and could manage my self... was wondering if someone here would have ever used it and could give me some hint...

Comment: find_and_modify and update are now marked as DEPRECATED?

Answer (score 21):

For those that came here after Googling `find_and_modify` and discovered it is deprecated (in PyMongo version 3.0, I think), the replacement is `find_one_and_update`.

Let's say you have a collection called `counters` and want to increment one of the counters:

```
db.counters.find_one_and_update({"_id": "counter-id"}, {"$inc":{"sequence_value":1}})
```

If you want the new document returned, instead of the original pre-updated one, the parameter to pass is `new` and not, as most documentation states, `returnNewDocument`:

```
db.counters.find_one_and_update({"_id": "counter-id"}, {"$inc":{"sequence_value":1}}, new=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since find_and_modify is deprecated use find_one_and_update method instead, use return_document parameter of find_one_and_update method to return either updated document or unupdated document.

```
update_object = collection_object.find_one_and_update({'_id': ObjectId(pk)}, {'$set': data}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

Here, return_document is set as ReturnDocument.AFTER, which will return a document after it's updated. If it's set as BEFORE, it'll return the document before it was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_one` to update a single document in a `collection` and set `upsert` to `True` to create a new `document` if condition doesn't match.

```
collection.update_one(
    filter = {"field1" : "value1"},
    update = {"$set" : {"field2" : "value2"}},
    upsert = True
)
```