# Python Motor MongoDB client findAndModify

Tags: python, mongodb, motordriver

Standard MongoDB driver for Python PyMongo has a method `find_and_modify`, but async client Motor doesn't have something like this. There are [some suggestions](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=findAndModify) in the documentation about `findAndModify` command but there is no an example how to use it.

How can I use `findAndModify` in Motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_and_modify` method seems to be deprecated, in client libraries at least.

There's a `find_one_and_update` method in PyMongo and Motor, which serves the same purpose.

There is more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165097/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any better solution than this:

```py
res = await db.command(
    'findAndModify',
    collection_name,
    query={'status': 'initial'},
    update={
        '$set': {'status': 'in_progress'}
    }
)

if not res['ok']:
    raise DbError(f'Error when findAndModify: {res}')

if doc := res['value']:
    td = TaskData(
        task_id=doc['task_id'],
        status=doc['status'],
    )
```